# how to send data from react to node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui, fetch

I'm Nodejs beginner, i'm using here rtsp-relay library for live streaming, currently it is working in frontend when URL is inlcuded, when creating a proxy object at server ' url: `rtsp://.....@..../Stream/Channel/10`,', but i dont want to include it there, i want to include it in frontend (user could write it in TextField)
should i use fetch and send, any advice/help on this ?
English is not my mother language, so could be mistakes.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const { proxy, scriptUrl } = require('rtsp-relay')(app);

const handle = proxy({
  url: `rtsp://.....@..../Stream/Channel/10`,
  // the URL above is credentials
  verbose: false,
  transport: 'tcp',
});

app.ws('/api/stream', handle );

app.get('/', (req, res) =>
  res.send(
    `hg`,
 
  ),
);

app.listen(5000);
```

React (material-ui):

```js
const updateUrl = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Box>
          <form
            onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
            <div>
              <Box>
                <Button
                  onClick={nulll}
                  aria-label="close-settings-popup">
                  <Close />
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </div>
            <FormGroup>
              <Box>
                <FormControl>
                  <TextField
                    type="text"
                    id="URL"
                    value={source}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label={
                      <Trans i18nKey="form.cameraForm.source">URL</Trans>
                    }
                  ></TextField>
                </FormControl>
              </Box>
            </FormGroup>
            <div>
              <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
                Accept
              </Button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Box>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };
```

this is what rtsp creator wrote:

[image]

Comment: You probably need to check your documentation for the library you are using real time streaming. In general if you want to fetch the stream from your server then you need to create or use the endpoint from the server and use fetch or axios to get the data in the frontend. Also, FYI, Your question is not clear

Comment: Im using that library to play live rtsp stream in frontend, and examples of that library have url of rtsp in node file, but i dont want to have it there, i want user to write url in frontend (rtsp-relay https://github.com/k-yle/rtsp-relay), i asked creator and he gave that answer above (image)

Comment: what do you mean you want to write the user in the frontend? what he is suggesting seems fine to me he is telling you to take the URL from the user and then that URL can be a proxy meaning it will be alias to the stream. I don't think I can make it more clear than that. I believe this npm package assumes you already have a backend server with express in place which I'm assuming you have. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @innocent should i use ’handleUpdate’ function and from there using fetch to send user given URL ? Could you give an example code on how to send that user given URL ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand with what you have asked, you need to create a websocket connection from the client-side.

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/ws') //Your url should be here
```

This is a basic webscoket connection using JavaScript native [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), you can use either other libraries like [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/).

Comment: could you provide more detailed answer (editing my code), like how to actually send that url from client side